# Split a number into 3 parts

Tags: python, python-2.7

If there is number I want to split that number into 3 parts.
for example: num = 4563289
these have to split into 45 63 289

I just count the numbers.

```
count = 0
num = int(raw_input("enter the number :"))
while (num > 0):
num = num//10
count = count + 1
print ("Total number of digits:", count)
if count % 2 == 0:
print('even')
else:
print('Odd')
```

Using this code to identify whether it is odd or even.
Based on that i want to split the numbers into 3 parts.

Comment: What is the exact logic by which a 7 digit numbers becomes 2, 2, and 3 digits?

Comment: Please fix your code. With python, indentation **is** important. I can infer what the indentation is, but you could even have it wrong in the first place, so...

Comment: exact question is to determine if the digits of a number can be divided into three continuous parts such that the third part is the sum of the other two. So first i want to split these into parts.

Answer (score 1):

Make the integer string and find its length. Something like this:

```
num = 4563289
num_str = (str(num))
a = int(len(num_str) / 3)

print('{} {} {}'.format(num_str[:a], num_str[a:2*a], num_str[2*a:]))
```

(result is `45 63 289`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your indentation is supposed to look like this:

```
count = 0
num = int(raw_input("enter the number :"))
while (num > 0):
    num = num//10
    count = count + 1
print ("Total number of digits:", count)
if count % 2 == 0:
    print('even')
else:
    print('Odd')
```

By the end, you cant split the number anymore, because it has been modified in the while-loop until it is 0. If you run it and let the program print the num variable at the end it always comes out as 0 because that is what you are telling the program to do. In my opinion its never a good idea to modify the original variable especially as its not easily retrievable.

Anyway, theres an easer way to tell whether the number of digits is odd or even, using the `len()` function:

```
num = int(raw_input("enter the number :"))   

num_str = str(num)

print ("Total number of digits: " + str(len(num_str)))

if len(num_str) % 2 == 0: 
    print ("Number of digits is even")
else: 
    print ("Number of digits is odd")
```

Converting the input to a string makes sense, because it makes its length easy to determine and helps us with slicing the number up later. Now  for the splicing, probably not the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
if len(num_str) >= 3:  
    newnum = str(num_str[0:2] + " " + num_str[2:4] + " " + num_str[4:])

print (newnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input('enter the Number you want check: ')

if num > 0 :

    for i in  range(0,num):
         if ( num % 2) == 0:
         print('its  a even number')
         break
    else:
     print('Its a odd number')
else:
  print('its even number')
```

Comment: Adding some explanation would make this answer more useful.